# Breakpoint set but not yet bound for some files when using a Dockerized node process

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-debugging

I have a server running inside a docker container that listens for a debugger on port 9229. Below is how my launch.json looks like

```
{
      "name": "Docker: Attach to Node",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "restart": true,
      "port": 9229,
      "address": "localhost",
      "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "remoteRoot": "/app/",
      "protocol": "inspector",
      "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**"
      ]
    }
```

Inside the main app folder I have 3 sub-folders as shown below,

> /app/api/v1

> /app/tests/specs/

> /app/utils/

I have the breakpoint set in multiple files across all these three subfolders but vs code is only recognizing the breakpoints set for the /app/api/v1 folder. For the breakpoints set in the rest of the folders, it says "Breakpoint set but not yet bound". Can someone please assist? I did go through similar questions in stack overflow but none of them helped.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by following the below steps.

1. Install Docker extension from VS Code marketplace.

[image]

2. Click on the Docker icon and then right-click on your container which has node server running and select “Attach to VS Code“.

[image]

3. Add below configuration in your launch.json

```
    {
      "name": "Docker: Attach to container",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "restart": true,
      "port": 9229,
      "address": "localhost",
      "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "remoteRoot": "/app",
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "cwd":"${workspaceFolder}",
      "protocol": "inspector",
      "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**"
      ],
    }
```

4. Click on Run and Debug and select "Docker: Attach to container" from the drop-down. The debugger should be attached.

Comment: Great, don’t forget to accept your answer, it will be helpful for other forum members.